# C++: floor unix timestamp to UTC month

Tags: c++, datetime, unix-timestamp

Assume I have a unix timetsamp

```
int timestamp=1594386202;
```

I want to write a function

```
int floor_to_month_utc(int timestamp);
```

that floors a timestamp it to the beginning of the the corresponding month (in UTC). In this example the function shall satisfy `1593561600 == floor_to_month_utc(1594386202)` because `1594386202` corresponds to `2020-07-10T13:03:22+00:00` UTC time and `1593561600` is the beginning of the corresponding month `2020-07-01T00:00:00+00:00`.

How can I do this in C++? (Actually I also need the ceil of the current timestamp to the next month timestamp but I think that I can write this myself if you give me a hint how to implement the floor function)

Comment: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono in c++20 or https://github.com/HowardHinnant/date before c++20 will help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [Alan Birtles](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5494370/alan-birtles) points out in the comments, this can easily be accomplished in C++20:

```
#include <chrono>

int
floor_to_month_utc(int timestamp)
{
    using namespace std::chrono;

    sys_seconds tp{seconds{timestamp}};
    year_month_day ymd = floor<days>(tp);
    sys_seconds result = sys_days{ymd.year()/ymd.month()/1};
    return result.time_since_epoch().count();
}
```

Explanation:

The first step is to put the input into the `<chrono>` type system.  It is understood that `timestamp` is a count of seconds since 1970-01-01 00:00:00 UTC (excluding leap seconds).  This is also known as [Unix Time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time).

`std::chrono::sys_seconds` is the C++20 type that corresponds to these semantics.  So `sys_seconds tp{seconds{timestamp}};` first converts `timestamp` to the duration `seconds`, and then to the `time_point` `sys_seconds`.

Next one must realize that this is a *calendrical* computation, not a *chronological* computation.  And the calendar being used is the civil calendar, which is modeled in C++20 `<chrono>`.  So the next step is to convert the `time_point` `tp` to a day in the civil calendar:

```
year_month_day ymd = floor<days>(tp);
```

`floor<days>` simply truncates the precision to `tp` to `days` precision (making it a count of days since 1970-01-01 00:00:00 UTC).

`ymd` is a `{year, month, day}` data structure, converted from the `days`-precision `time_point` and has type `std::chrono::year_month_day`.  Both `ymd` and `floor<days>(tp)` contain exactly the same information.  But the information is stored in two different data structures:  `{year, month, day}` vs `{count of days}`.

The next step is to find the first day of the year and month referred to by `ymd`.  This is simply the expression `ymd.year()/ymd.month()/1`.

This can be converted back to the `{count of days}` data structure with:

```
sys_days{ymd.year()/ymd.month()/1}
```

`std::chrono::sys_days` is simply a type alias for the type of the expression `floor<days>(tp)`, which has type:

```
time_point<system_clock, days>
```

Next the `sys_days` data structure is implicitly converted to `seconds`-precision, and the integral amount is extracted and returned from that data structure.

A [preview of the C++20 `<chrono>` library is here](https://github.com/HowardHinnant/date) and can be used with C++11/14/17.  To port the above function to this preview library simply add `"date/date.h"` and `using namespace date;`.  `"date/date.h"` is a header-only library and so requires no installation.

This can be exercised like so:

```
std::cout << floor_to_month_utc(1594386202) << '\n';
```

which outputs:

```
1593561600
```

---

It is instructive to compare the above code to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62834269/576911) which gives a different result:

```
1593626076
```

The reason the result is different goes back to the distinction between *calendrical* computations, and *chronological* computations.  Calendrical computations are done with respect to some calendar (civil, Chinese, Julian, whatever).  Whereas chronological computations operate only on fixed (regular) units of time.  Calendrical months and years don't have regular lengths of time.

The C++20 `<chrono>` library can perform chronological computations with `months` and `years` though.  This is sometimes the right answer when dealing with physical or biological processes that stretch on for months or years.  Such processes don't care about human made calendars.  So in this case it makes sense to deal with the *average* length of months and years.

This statement:

```
floor<months>(sys_seconds{seconds{timestamp}})
```

simply divides the time since the [Unix Time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time) epoch into regular, even months, with each month being exactly 2,629,746 seconds long (the average length of the civil month).  So this answer is correct if one desired a chronological computation with hypothetical uniform months (an entirely different calendar if you will).

Comment: It seems that if I floor to `days` instead of `months` both, the chronological and calendrical functions yield the same result. Is this always true?

Comment: If I'm understanding the description of the code, this would only yield the same result if the input time point is within the first day of the month.

Comment: I mean if I write `sys_days{ymd}` instead of `sys_days{ymd.year()/ymd.month()/1}` in your answer and `date::floor<date::days>` instead of `date::floor<date::months>` in my answer. Then for example both functions yield output `1594339200` for the input `1594386202` (not the first day of the month).

Comment: Yes.  Given `sys_days x = floor<days>(t)`, `sys_days{year_month_day{x}}` is an identity operation.  It is simply converting losslessly between the `{year, month, day}` and `{count of days}` data structures (back and forth).

Comment: Does this mean that indeed chronological and calendrical floor to UTC days is the same? I thought the described modifications make the two functions compute the chronological and calendrical floor for _days_ and then they are the same due to this identity.

Comment: Yes, for the purpose of this discussion, calendrical and chronological floor (or any other arithmetic operation) is the same for `days`.  The *reason* it is the same is because Unix Time neglects leap seconds, and so all days are 86400 seconds.  If we change clocks to `utc_clock`, (where some days are 86401 seconds) then this is no longer true.

Answer (score 0):

EDIT:
This is the wrong chronological computation.

---

As proposed in the comments, using the `date.h` header of Howard Hinnant, <del>the following seems to do what I want</del> (using `int64_t` to avoid the 2038 bug):

```
#include"date.h"

int64_t floor_to_month_utc(int64_t timestamp){
    using namespace std::chrono;
    const auto dp = date::floor<date::months>(system_clock::time_point(seconds(timestamp)));
    return duration_cast<seconds>(dp.time_since_epoch()).count();
}
```